# I do not know how to end game when specific block is touched in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to make it so when my character touches the "v" block the game quits. What I tried was to find all blocks that are "v" and put them in the list. If player colliderect with any in list of "v" game will quit.

I think this should work although it does not seem to be working. Whenever I run it when I touch the "v" block nothing happens.

Here is my code

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
WINDOW_SIZE = (600, 400)
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE, 0, 32)
display = pygame.Surface((300, 200))

player_image = pygame.image.load("Jacques clone-1.png (1).png").convert()
player_image.set_colorkey((255,255,255))

location = [50, 50]

#boolean for movement
moving_right = False
moving_left = False

scroll = [0, 0]

Stay_right = True

game_map1 = """
-----------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------
xx----------x----------------------------------------
----------vvvv---------------------xxx----------------
---------xooo----------------------------------------
xxxxxxxxxooooxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
""".splitlines()

game_map = [list(lst) for lst in game_map1]

tl = {}
tl["v"] = spike_img = pygame.image.load('dirt.png')
tl["o"] = dirt_img = pygame.image.load('grass.png')
tl["x"] = grass_img = pygame.image.load('grass.png')

player_rect = pygame.Rect(50, 50, 25, 25)
momentum = 0
air_timer = 0

#adding tiles list that are hit for movement
def collision_test(rect, tiles):
    hit_list = []
    for tile in tiles:
        if rect.colliderect(tile):
            hit_list.append(tile)
            #print(hit_list)
    return hit_list

def move(rect, movement, tiles):
    collision_types = {'top': False, 'bottom': False, 'right': False, 'left': False}
    rect.x += movement[0]
    hit_list = collision_test(rect, tiles)
    for tile in hit_list:
        if movement[0] > 0:
            rect.right = tile.left
            collision_types['right'] = True
        elif movement[0] < 0:
            rect.left = tile.right
            collision_types['left'] = True
    rect.y += movement[1]
    hit_list = collision_test(rect, tiles)
    for tile in hit_list:
        if movement[1] > 0:
            rect.bottom = tile.top
            collision_types['bottom'] = True
        elif movement[1] < 0:
            rect.top = tile.bottom
            collision_types['top'] = True
    return rect, collision_types

run = True
while run:
    display.fill((146, 244, 255))

    scroll[0] += (player_rect.x - scroll[0] - 130)


    tile_rects = []
    y = 0
    for line_of_symbols in game_map:
        x = 0
        for symbol in line_of_symbols:
            if symbol in tl:
                display.blit(tl[symbol], (x * 16 - scroll[0], y * 16 - scroll[1]))
            if symbol != "-":
                tile_rects.append(pygame.Rect(x * 16, y * 16, 16, 16))
            x += 1
        y += 1

    list_ofspike = []
    y2 = 0
    for lineofsymbols in game_map:
        x2 = 0
        for symbols in lineofsymbols:
            if symbols == "v":
                list_ofspike.append(pygame.Rect(x2 * 16, y2 * 16, 16, 16))
            x2 += 1
        y2 += 1

    for spike in list_ofspike:
        if player_rect.colliderect(spike):
            pygame.quit()

    player_movement = [0, 0]
    if moving_right:
        player_movement[0] += 2
    if moving_left:
        player_movement[0] -= 2
    player_movement[1] += momentum
    momentum += 0.3
    if momentum > 3:
        momentum = 3

    player_rect, collisions = move(player_rect, player_movement, tile_rects)

    if collisions['bottom']:
        air_timer = 0
        momentum = 0
    else:
        air_timer += 1

    if Stay_right:
        display.blit(player_image, (player_rect.x - scroll[0], player_rect.y - scroll[1]))
    else:
        display.blit(pygame.transform.flip(player_image, 1, 0 ),(player_rect.x - scroll[0], player_rect.y - scroll[1]))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moving_right = True
                Stay_right = True
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moving_left = True
                Stay_right = False
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                if air_timer < 6:
                    momentum = -5
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moving_right = False
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moving_left = False

    screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(display, (WINDOW_SIZE)), (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not detect a collision with the spikes, because your collision detection works too perfectly.
When you move the player then you ensure, that the player does not intersect any object, thus the player does not intersect a spike, too.

You have to test if the player touches a spike. Increase the player rectangle by 1 in direction and use the increased rectangle to do the collision test with the spikes:

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    test_rect = pygame.Rect(player_rect.left-1, player_rect.top-1,
                            player_rect.width+2, player_rect.height+2)
    for spike in list_ofspike:
        if test_rect.colliderect(spike):
            pygame.quit() 

    # [...]
```